# Show Three Sets are Equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Say I have three sets $S_1, S_2, S_3$, and I want to show that they are equal. Is it enough to show that $S_1 \subset S_2$, $S_2 \subset S_3$, and $S_3 \subset S_1$?

I think yes:

(1) If $S_1 \subset S_2$ and $S_2 \subset S_3$, then $S_1 \subset S_3$. This result, together with $S_3 \subset S_1$, implies that $S_1 = S_3$.

(2) If, $S_1 = S_3$ and $S_1 \subset S_2$, then $S_3 \subset S_2$. This result, with $S_2 \subset S_3$ shows that $S_2 = S_3$.

(3) If $S_1 = S_3$ and $S_2 = S_3$, then $S_1 = S_2$.

So I think yes, but I'm planning to use this idea to prove something else, and I don't want to waste my time on a faulty premise! Thanks.

Comment: The answer to your question is “yes.” Just observe $$S_1\subseteq S_2\subseteq S_3\subseteq S_1$$ which implies equality throughout.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes.  And I think most instructors would accept it without as much (excellent) exposition as you gave.

Comment: You are correct. Note that $A\subset B$ is really an abbreviation for $\forall x\, (x\in A\implies x\in B).$ From the unabbreviated form we obtain $(A\subset B\land B\subset A)\iff \forall x \,(x\in A\iff x\in B)\iff A=B,$ and we also obtain  $(A\subset B\land B\subset C)\implies A\subset C.$....  From this we have $((A_1\subset A_2\land  A_2\subset A_3)\land A_3\subset A_1)\implies (A_1\subset A_3\land A_3\subset A_1)\implies A_1=A_3,$  while permuting the subscripts $(1,2,3)$ to $(2,3,1)$ will yield $A_2=A_1.$